# as.character() with numeric loses precision when a string is transformed into numeric

Tags: java, r, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

In R I want to run following code:

```
str <- "2811.1019192874087"
val <- as.numeric(str)
str2 <- as.character(val)
print(str2)
print(val)
```

It prints:

```
"2811.10191928741"
 2811.102
```

But I want:

```
"2811.1019192874087"
 2811.102
```

In short, I would like the precision with as.character() not to be lost. I've already tried using `options(digits = x)` where `x` is a number of my choice, but this only changes the output and not the value itself. I also tried using `trimws(format(round(x, k), nsmall=k))`. This system seems to work but unfortunately the output is of type `character` instead of being of type `numeric`.

If I do the same thing in Java it works correctly. I run the following code:

```
String str = "2811.1019192874087";
double val = Double.parseDouble(str);
String str2 = String.valueOf(val);
System.out.println(str2);
System.out.println(val);
```

It prints:

```
2811.1019192874087
2811.1019192874087
```

How can I solve the problem in R? Thank you so much

Comment: It's not `as.numeric` that is "losing" precision, the default formatting that `print` uses is rounding the value it is passed.  `sprintf("%4.13f", val)` prints `[1] "2811.1019192874087"`, demonstrating that precision is preserved by `as.numeric()`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: @jogo see my tags

Comment: `print(val, digits=15)` show more digits (I dont understand this: "options(digits = ...) only changes the printed value but not the value itself") as using more digits shows the value which R truncates in printing to 7 by default)

Comment: as.character(as.numeric("2811.1019192874087")) prints "2811.10191928741" instead "2811.1019192874087". In Java this works correctly

Comment: @WietsedeVries same problem with sprintf. sprintf("%s", 2811.1019192874087) prints "2811.10191928741"

Comment: AH, in your code you take the str2 from val, not from str. How about `sprintf("%4.13f", val)` then?

Comment: @WietsedeVries yeah. I think I should adopt this system even if I don't like to manually give the precision

Comment: Given that your original data is a string you could choose to measure the nchar before and after the period and paste it into your sprintf statement like so: `str2 <- sprintf(paste0("%", paste0(unlist(lapply(strsplit(str, "\\."), nchar)), collapse = "."), "f"), val)`. It makes the code dynamic although you are clearly giving up readability

Comment: @WietsedeVries that could help me. Thanks